# Command line tool for removing orphaned packages?

Tags: package-management

Just exactly that. A command line equivalent of **gtkorphan**? An Ubuntu equivalent of `urpme --auto-orphans`? Please do not suggest `apt-get autoremove` as it's not exactly the same thing.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[deborphan](http://packages.ubuntu.com/nl/saucy/deborphan)

- [Man page](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/saucy/man1/deborphan.1.html)
- The command `deborphan` itself will display a list
- If you wish to see all the packages which aren't required you can run:

  ```
  deborphan --guess-all
  ```
- You do not need root privileges to use this tool, it reads the installed package lists and it won't remove any packages itself, merely tell you what it thinks you should remove

[image]

Installation

```
sudo apt-get install deborphan
```

---

Just for the those users that do not use command line: [Ubuntu tweak tool](http://ubuntu-tweak.com/) is a graphical front end that also installs deborphan.