# Retrieve and delete obsoletes packages

Tags: apt, package-management, upgrade, 18.04, do-release-upgrade

I just upgrade from ubuntu 16.04 to Ubuntu 18.04.

Before then end of the upgrade, it asked me if I want to delete obsoletes packages and packages installed automatically no more used.

I answered "no", because I need to keep some packages (php7.0).
Now I migrated to the newer packages (php7.2) how do I retrieve and delete obsoletes packages ?

I tried `apt autoremove` but it seems not to delete obsolete packages.
What is the command used by `do-release-upgrade` to retrieve these packages ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I get a list of obsolete packages?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/98223/how-do-i-get-a-list-of-obsolete-packages) and [Command line tool for removing orphaned packages?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/389382/command-line-tool-for-removing-orphaned-packages)

Answer (score 0):

[This answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/98223/how-do-i-get-a-list-of-obsolete-packages) has a couple of examples on how to retrieve obsolete packages.

It should be fairly easy then to remove them.

A simple oneliner (**warning not tested!**) can be:

```
aptitude show '~o' | grep Package: | cut -d' ' -f2 | xargs -n1 -l --verbose sudo apt-get purge -y
```

Answer (score 0):

I use

```
apt list --installed | grep -v xenial
```

to list all packages that are *not* in Xenial (change release name accordingly, of course). Then I remove them manually; I am extremely wary of automating package management tasks.